Botframework-webchat-Getiing window.WebChat.createStore is not a function
I have a microsoft bot framework project hosted on azure bot service which i use in my angular project.
My task is to remove the dependancy of azure service so that i can host the bot framework project directly on IIS server without using any azure secret code or direct line token.
After some RnD i found that it is possible to host the bot on IIS and then by using botframework-webchat pack you can invoke your bot hosted on IIS.
My question is:

is the above approach correct? and is it possible to achieve?

I tried using botframework-webchat in local project for demo with node js version 20 and angular version 18. But on running the code i get window.WebChat.createStore is not a function.


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
declare global {
interface Window {
WebChat:any
}
}
window.WebChat = window.WebChat || {}
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
standalone: true,
})
export class AppComponent {
ngOnInit(){
const store =window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }:{dispatch:any}) => (next: (arg0: any) => any) =>
(action: { type: string; }) => {
  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
    //service to invoke bot with bot URL
  }
  return next(action);
}); 

window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
{
directLine: { postActivity: (activity: any) => store.dispatch({ type: 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY', payload: { activity } }) },
userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID', // Optionally set a user ID
username: 'YOUR_USERNAME' // Optionally set a username
},
document.getElementById('webchat')
);
}
}
